# Show Featured Image in Wordpress Editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a website with `wordpress` but I cannot see featured image in both `screen options` or editor

[image: Ed]

[image]

This is blank `Wordpress` install 5.3.2, I develop new web from scratch so I don't think problem related to other plugins

Comment: Did you some how disabled the WP Rest API feature? Because just seeing the layout it is not using the Rest API Facilities

Comment: I have no idea about WP Rest API. I just download fresh install and create this web with blank theme from scratch

Comment: It is really hard to tell by just seeing the screenshot only. You can change the theme or try to re-install the whole thing. But before that you can open your wp-config.php file and set define('WP_DEBUG', true); to see if there is any error or not. Hope that will help :)

Comment: WP_DEBUG shows nothing

Comment: If it is possible then re-install the WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your themes functions.php and paste the following code inside:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

Hope you can use it to solve your problem.

Comment: You save my day. Thank you, that's it